# Applying Multiple Effects on XNA Models While Retaining Model Material Appearance

Tags: model, xna, effect, lighting

How might one go about applying various different effects to a model while still maintaining properties for the different materials on different parts of the model?

I am using the Model class in xna and have created models in blender (using the .fbx file format). As far as I am aware, loading a model through xna's content pipeline stores information about different materials in various BasicEffect instances (for instance specular power and diffuse colour). What I want to do is apply various different custom effects to the models (including all the point lights in my world) while still having glossy sections of models retain their shiny appearance (as an example). My idea was to never remap a model but to keep the BasicEffect instances as a reference to how certain materials should look. In this case I would need to manually draw each ModelMeshPart after applying the right effect. Am I thinking along the right lines to applying a lot of global effects to my models? Is there perhaps a better way of accessing material information in a .fbx file? Ought I to remap my models with one effect with all the techniques I could need crammed into it?

Answer (score 0):

In the draw loop, you would already be iterating over the meshes and calling individual draws for each mesh part.  So inside that loop, rather than using the effect attached to the model, put settings (from the model or otherwise) onto your own effect, apply it, and use it to draw the mesh.

The XNA developers have noted that the content importer and Model class are necessarily specialized to make it simple for a beginning programmer to draw a model.  Unfortunately, that makes them unsuited for techniques that you want to achieve.  If you want to do more advanced drawing, you'll likely need to extend the Model class, and use the base as a geometry/texture storage medium.